# Asp net core identity: how to get default ApplicationDbContext outside controller?

Tags: asp.net, identity

I use Net Core 2.1 and I need to do some preparations on startup which require several direct Identity database queries.

I tried:

```
using (var serviceScope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                    .CreateScope())
{
    var identityDb = serviceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
}
```

these lines produce exception: Cannot resolve scoped service 'Ecoc.Data.ApplicationDbContext' from root provider. 
Is there a way to get database context in arbitrary place of code?

Answer (score 1):

Use [IServiceScopeFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicescopefactory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) instead of [IServiceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider?view=netcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and then create a scope and use its ServiceProvider.

Related to you example:

```
var identityDb = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the correct approach here (they access Session from arbitrary class as example)
https://neelbhatt.com/2018/02/10/implement-session-in-net-core2-0/